# how do you echo input tag of type image and get to load image in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am trying to echo out an submit button input tag of the type image, but i cant get it to load the image, it is stored in a directory called imgs in the public_html directory of my site. The code that i have is as such:

```
echo '<input type="image" src="'.base_url("img/sign_up_0.png").'">';
```

i have the url helper auto-loaded and use it else were to load images in links the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
 $image_path = base_url()."imgs/sign_up_0.png";
 echo '<input type="image" src="'.$image_path.'">';
```

Comment: Just a more cleaner approach : 

 `$image_path = base_url()."img/sign_up_0.png"; `

 `echo "<input type='image' src='{$image_path}' />"; `

Comment: If you inspect with firebug (for firefox) and go over the image you can see the path, is correct? the console return some error?

Comment: i have checked the path, it is right, that was one of the first things i checked

Comment: if the path is ok the image must be view.. no error into yur browser? Can we see your page to inspect the problem?

Comment: i load the same image in links to a page on my site and it loads fine

Comment: if you print in your page this: echo($image_path);

Comment: the problem is here. http://www.ground-score.com/img/sign_up_0.png" donesn't find the image in this path

Comment: i can post the whole form if u want i am just using a test button to get it to load i was using in xampp the butten i plan to use i will add to the code

Comment: In your site where is this image? you must have root/img/your_image

Comment: yes because doens't find the image in that path  ground-score.com/img/sign_up_0.png where is your image'

Comment: public_html/imgs/contact_0.png, it is the same image i use in the nav bar at the side

Comment: it wont be in the nav on the contact page, only in the nav on other pages

Comment: If you change the code with mine you can see the image? After you can put it where you want, the question is to see correctly the image that doesn't appear

Comment: it did it, i feel stupid now that i didnt catch a simple type-o, i have had trouble with getting the path right before and figured it was my coding and not my typing lol